# How to make a textbox that can limit the user can only write the input from 0000 to FFFF only. c#

Tags: c#

This is the code I write that only accepts numbers or only characters. I dk the way that can only  limit the user can only write the input from 0000 to FFFF only.

Please Guide me
Thank You

```
public partial class TextBox_Numbers_Characters : Form
{
    public TextBox_Numbers_Characters()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TXTB_ONLY_CHAR_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void TXTB_ONLY_NUMBER_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `e.Handled = new Regex("[a-fA-F0-9]").IsMatch(e.KeyChar);`

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using one of the following statements.

I also added `Ctrl + C`, `Ctrl + X` and `Ctrl + V` exceptions, so the user is still able to copy and paste inside the specific input field.

```
char c = e.KeyChar;

if ((c==Keys.V && e.Control) || (c==Keys.C && e.Control) || (c==Keys.X && e.Control)) {
    e.Handled = true;
}
else {
    if (!(Char.IsControl(e.c)|| (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')))
   {
   e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

You can also do it using this method.

Add the following to your `XAML`

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="OnPreviewTextInput">
```

Then implement this in your `.cs` file

```
private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    int hexNumber;
    e.Handled = !int.TryParse(e.Text, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out hexNumber);
}
```

Comment: What if the user makes a mistake while typing and types an F when they wanted a D? Backspace isn't in the ranges specified, so it's "handled", likewise for delete.

Comment: Added `!Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)` so that all control keys are excluded. And included another method I found.

Comment: That's improved, though it does introduce the issue that Ctrl+V/Shift+Insert now works, and doesn't prevent right-click->Paste. Though these are OK if you're pasting a value in the range.

Comment: Honestly now you got me hooked, I'm going to see what I can do to make them work.

Comment: I added exclusion for Ctrl C, Ctrl V and Ctrl X